# Angular typeahead: let Enter key take the highest priority

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a typeahead (angular-ui-bootstrap) being used as a search entry field.

Too bad my manager insist to mix the typeahead and regular search.  Meaning users can select the result from typeahead or just hit enter key to start a regular search (with whatever typed in the textbox).

I used debounce 250ms to prevent searching on every keyup event.

When users stop typing, and hit the Enter key, it always waited for all the (typeahead)result to return then it start the regular search (for Enter key).

So if the type ahead result has many rows, if will cause latency for the Enter key to be fired (to start the regular search).  Is there a way I can cancel/ or stop all the type ahead action and let the Enter key take the highest priority? (when the Enter got hit, immediately start the regular search).

I am using AngularJs for this project.

I personally thought we shouldn't mix typeahead and regular search together though.